# Draw vector circle MapBox/Leaflet Android

Tags: android, leaflet, geometry, mapbox

how can I draw a vector circle with MapBox (integrated with gradle, so i have the newest version) on Android. It should be exactly like the Mapbox/Leaflet.js one: center, radius in km, color, ...

I've found the [iOS equivalent](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/drawing-circle/) but there seems to be any explanations whatsoever as to how to do that on Android (If possible)...

Thinking about it, I could replace the marker image with a high-res circle, but that'd scale and i don't want it to.